# exportBarCode\n\nAttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_sql_query

Tags: python

```
def exportPairCode(self,requestParam):
    try:
    
        if self.getDatabaseStatus() == False:
            return self.errorPage ('800',{self.databasePath}) 

        import pandas as pd

        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.databasePath, isolation_level=None,
                            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
        
        db_df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT CartonQR AS Carton,PairQRCode AS Pair,IsBilled,IsScanned FROM PairDetail", conn)
        db_df.to_csv(requestParam['exportPath'], index=False)
        
        return 200, self.returnJSON({"status":"OK"}) 

    except:
        return self.errorLog(sys)
```

I have update pandas version latest still showing errro
please help me out
code write in python 3.7